# What links do we need enabled for Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy, android-gradle-plugin, http-proxy

I'm working at a corporate location where we have restricted access to network. The hurdle that I'm facing is that I'm supposed to do some research on Android development and the network is not what I wanted it to be. I have installed Android Studio and created a new project. But as soon as the project is loaded, gradle sync operation starts and fails after not finding JUnit & similar dependencies.

I have already added the proxy settings in Android Studio and SDK manager, but I believe I'll have to request for unblocking some of the URLs that Android Studio needs access to. I couldn't find any such list, can someone please help me with the same?

I have tried running Fiddler to see which requests are being blocked, but I see only 1 URL and that is `clients1.google.com` but I'm not sure that is the only thing needed.

Comment: You probably need to unblock maven since most dependencies are pulled from there.

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy, as I mentioned its my workplace, they have corporate rules defined to block unwanted network using firewalls. I can only request to allow certain blocked links..

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy I found the answer and have posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of hits and misses, I have found the answer to this question. The `build.gradle` file for the project has the answer to this. It calls a function `jcenter()` which internally calls the libraries available at `http://jcenter.bintray.com/`. So, the entire list for Android Studio development including the SDK would be:

- http://dl.google.com:443
- http://dl-ssl.google.com:443
- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/*
- https://developer.android.com (for Android Studio downloads and documentations)
- http://jcenter.bintray.com/

Thanks for all the help provided.